An upper bound for $E[\Phi(aX+b)\Phi(cY+d)]$ for correlated bivariate normal distribution
I am working on some problem related to the computation of the expectation
$$E[\Phi(\sigma_xX+\mu_x)\Phi(\sigma_yY+\mu_y)].$$
Here $X,Y$ are standard normal distribution with correlation coefficient $\rho$ and $\Phi$ is the cdf of a standard normal distribution.
I am wondering if there is an upper bound for this expectation. It is expected that the upper bound contains parameters of $(\mu_x,\mu_y,\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\rho)$ as much as possible. Trivial bounds like $E[\Phi(\sigma_xX+\mu_x)\Phi(\sigma_yY+\mu_y)] \le E[\Phi(\sigma_xX+\mu_x)]$ cannot be tight in subsequent analysis.
Remark: There is an upper bound when $\mu_x = \mu_y =0$ and $\sigma_x = \sigma_y = \sigma\le 1$. In fact, one can show that
$$E[\Phi(\sigma X)\Phi(\sigma Y)] \le \frac 14 + \frac 14 \sigma^2\rho .$$
The proof is made by expanding the normal cdf $\Phi(x)$ to the summation of Hermite polynomials. However, it seems hard to extend the result to the case when $\mu_x, \mu_y\neq 0$.
